# Is it possible to get all post variables in ExpressionEngine, like you could in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, expressionengine

In a controller in CI you could get all post variables by doing something like this:

```
$data = $this->input->post();
```

In EE (built off of CI by the same people) the analogous syntax would be:

```
$data = $this->EE->input->post();
```

The only issue is that instead of an array with all of the data, you get a boolean of false.

Is there some way of getting an array of all post data, using ExpressionEngine rather than the POST superglobal?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the source code, read it from there. It was not mentioned in the documentation and I don't know where to get the source from.

Comment: Thanks.  There was a solution that I just kind of winged:          foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $data[$key] = $this->EE->input->post($key);
        }  This works fine, for anyone who finds value in this question

Comment: @Mike_K, post your solution as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, the way to get results similar to CI within EE for all elements of a POST, while still leveraging the security features of EE is the following:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
     $data[$key] = $this->EE->input->post($key);
}
```

Since you can access POST vars by name, looping through them in $_POST, then explicitly calling each will yield the desired result.

Answer (score 23):

Try native

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter 
$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html