# Is there any other option to insert data in the database using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a one form with more than 30 fields. I know how to submit the data in the database using CodeIgniter. I just want to know that is there any other option to submit the data without writing the whole input postcode. I mean check below code. It looks very big.

```
$reg_dat = array(
    'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
    'name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
    'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
    'school' =>$this->input->post('school'),
    'course' =>$this->input->post('course'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email')

    'a' => $this->input->post('a'),
    'b' => $this->input->post('b'),
    'c' => $this->input->post('c'),
    'd' =>$this->input->post('d'),
    'e' =>$this->input->post('e'),
    'f' => $this->input->post('f')

    'g' => $this->input->post('g'),
    'h' => $this->input->post('h'),
    'i' => $this->input->post('i'),
    'j' =>$this->input->post('j'),
    'k' =>$this->input->post('k'),
    'l' => $this->input->post('l')

     and so on..
);
```

Is there any other option to make the above code in the small code?

Comment: Now I am confused, I got two different an answer which is the best now @Himanshu or Keith?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get all post variables in ExpressionEngine, like you could in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128198/is-it-possible-to-get-all-post-variables-in-expressionengine-like-you-could-in)

Comment: @ankitsuthar, If the question id duplicate than why you updated your answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$all_data = $_POST;
```

Above mentioned line will make an array with keys same as the column name as you mentioned in your question, so there is no need to write so many lines are you shown in your post.

OR

```
$all_data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);  // returns all POST items with XSS filter. This is secure way.
```

And then to insert all that data in DB, we have syntax in Codeigniter is:

```
$this->db->insert('table_name',$all_data);  // Write this in your model.
```

So in `table_name` all the data will be inserted.

Comment: sure. @Hybreeder.

Comment: Is it mandatory that form fields name and table columns name should be same?

Comment: Its not mandatory, but if they won't be same then you can not have approach that we suggested in answers. Actually the array you would pass to insert code of Codeigniter, should have the keys same as column names.  So if your form elements have the same name as column, it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666787/validation-is-not-working-in-codeigniter/46666962#46666962

Comment: @Hybreeder, I am talking about this one only. I meant to say, as my answer has solved your issue then can you accept this ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting popup from Stackoverflow that  I will accept your answer after 11 mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156362/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-himanshu-upadhyay).

Answer (score 1):

While using all `$_POST` elements can be quick, it's probably best to whitelist the ones you want to insert.

```
$whitelist = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ...);

$reg_dat = array();

foreach($key => $value in $whitelist){
    $reg_dat[$value] = $this->input->post($value);
}
```

In terms of security, ensuring that you're using XSS filters and any other validation you may want to do on these elements prior to insertion. Also, make sure that your database driver is mysqli, pdo or some other, more secure one than mysql.

Based on your below comment about the `$_POST` keys not lining up with your database columns, you could do the following.

```
$whitelist = array();
$whitelist['a'] = 'database_column_for_a';
$whitelist['b'] = 'database_column_for_b';

$reg_dat = array();

foreach($postKey => $databaseColumn in $whitelist){
    $reg_dat[$databaseColumn] = $this->input->post($postKey);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666787/validation-is-not-working-in-codeigniter/46666962#46666962

Answer (score 0):

If you have POST fields names and MySQL columns names exactly same then just do this

```
$reg_dat = $_POST
```

And enter that array into DB

Answer (score 0):

Simply Do:

```
$reg_dat = $this->input->post();
```

That's all. You will get `$reg_dat` array which contains all post input field and you can directly insert it in Codeigniter like.

> Note: For Use, this directly makes sure your input name and your column name must be same.

```
$this->db->insert('table_name',$reg_dat);
```

For `get`,

```
$this->input->get();
```