# Validation is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

Validation is not working. All the form fields are coming dynamically. It depends on the user how many fields he chooses.If he chooses 2 and it will display 2 fields in the view. If select 3 then it will display 3 fields and so on.I have more than 30 fields

I set 3 arrays(for testing purpose I set only 3. It will be total no of fields ) in my form validation page. If I remove the last array than validation is working because I am getting only 2 fields in the view. I am not able to use the more than 2 array in my form validation page.

Is it mandatory to require the number of fields in view is equal to a number of sets of rules array in form validation?

View

This is my dynamic view page

```
<?php
   echo form_open('formbuilder_control/enxample_from_view');
    foreach ($data as $key) {// I am getting output
     $exp_fields_name=$key->fields_name;
     $exp_fields_type=$key->fields_type;
     $exp_form_elements=$key->form_elements;

    $abc=explode(',',$exp_form_elements);
        foreach ($abc as $value) {
          if ($exp_fields_name == $value) {?>
          <div class="form-group row label-capitals">
                  <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $exp_fields_name;?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input type="<?php echo $exp_fields_type;?>" name="<?php echo $exp_fields_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $value;?>" class="form-control" />
                   <?php echo form_error($exp_fields_name); ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                  <?php 
           }}}?>

              <div class="form-buttons-w btn_strip">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary margin-10">
              </div>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
    'test'=>array(

     array('field' =>'firstname', 
           'label' => 'First Name',
            'rules' => 'required'
    ),
        array('field' => 'lastname',
              'label' => 'lastname',
              'rules' => 'required'
              ),

     array('field' => 'middlename',
           'label' => 'middlename',
           'rules' => 'required'
         )
     ),
);
```

Controller

```
public function test()
{

        if($this->form_validation->run('test') == TRUE) 
        {
                echo "working";
        }
$this->load->view('test1');
}
```

Comment: Please share the downvote reason so that I can improve in future

Comment: Why you want to keep three validation rules while the form does not have three fields?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, Right

Comment: I have two forms. In the first form, fields are firstname, lastname,middlename. and in the second form, fields are firstname and lastname.I have to use only one set of rules.

Comment: Why you want to keep three validation rules while the form does not have three fields?

Comment: I want to use only one set of rules for both the form.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will fail. Your validation rules define a 'middlename' field as `required`, and that field doesn't even exist in the form.

A missing field cannot satisfy a `required` rule.

Comment: So is there any other option to handle this?

Comment: To handle what? I don't even understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have two forms. In the first form, fields are firstname, lastname,middlename. and in the second form, fields are firstname and lastname.I have to use only one set of rules.

Comment: So is it possible to use like this way?

Comment: No. The validation rules are essentialy server-side definitions of a form; you can't have 2 different forms with only one set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you want to have one set of validation rules and you have two different forms to validate, you can do it using very nice option with Codeigniter's validation `callback` function.
I am going to post a simple example here:

Your view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php echo form_open('formbuilder_control/test');?>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <input type="hidden" name="which_form" value="first_form">
         <?php echo form_error('firstname'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <?php echo form_error('lastname'); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('formbuilder_control/test');?>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <input type="hidden" name="which_form" value="second_form">
         <?php echo form_error('firstname'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <?php echo form_error('lastname'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="middlename">
         <?php echo form_error('middlename'); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>


<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class YourController extends CI_Controller {

    public function save() 
    {
        //.... Your controller method called on submit

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // Build validation rules array
        $validation_rules = array(
                                array(
                                    'field' => 'A',
                                    'label' => 'Field A',
                                    'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean'
                                    ),
                                array(
                                    'field' => 'B',
                                    'label' => 'Field B',
                                    'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean'
                                    ),
                                array(
                                    'field' => 'C',
                                    'label' => 'Field C',
                                    'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_required_inputs'
                                    )
                                );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);
        $valid = $this->form_validation->run();

        // Handle $valid success (true) or failure (false)

    }


    public function required_inputs()
    {
        if( $this->input->post('which_form') == "second_form" && !$this->input->post('middlename'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('middlename', 'Middle name is required!');
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

From above example you can see `required_inputs` function is just like a normal function, where you can write any php code.
So what I would advice is, have one hidden field in both of the forms, jus to check which form got submitted, and then set callback function for `middlename` validation rule and in that function, check which form is submitted by user, and based on it, return TRUE or FALSE.

I hope this will get you the whole idea what you can do.

You just need to add a hidden field with different value in each the forms and check the value in callback function to decide whether you should apply the third validation rule or not.

Comment: Actually, I have dynamic form, It will return 2 fields or three fields or one field not sure. It totally depends on the customer How may form field he requires. that's why I used only one set of rules

Comment: In public function required_inputs(), I have more than 30 fields that I have to use each input post in the if condition? like you did ! $this->input->post('A') and so on

Comment: Yes, you need to do for the fields which either may come or not.

Comment: This is not a good thing to write all the field in IF condition.

Comment: @Hybreeder, the validation rules is a bunch of arrays, so we can not write any condition in array itself, so Codeigniter has this great feature that we can set a callback function to our validation rules and it will allow you to manage your validation rules based on any conditions you want.

Comment: It totally depends on the user which field he chooses. I have more than 30 fields and If I write like this if( ! $this->input->post('A') AND ! $this->input->post('B') AND $this->input->post('C') and so on) then I don't think this is the good idea

Comment: No man, you mis-understood my suggestion, in that callback function you just need to check that one hidden field posted along with the form. You need to put `<input type="hidden" name="which_form" value="first">` and same field should be there in the other form but with different `value="second"` so in the callback function you need to check if you get $this->->input->post('which_form') == "first"; or "second" and based on that, return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Can you share the example of code for better understand?

Comment: Is this helpful @Hybreeder?

Comment: Nope till now, I am trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156426/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-himanshu-upadhyay).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have flexible sets of rules with a minimum of code. Consider this `form_validation.php` example

```
<?php

$first_last = array(
  array('field' => 'firstname',
    'label' => 'First Name',
    'rules' => 'required'
  ),
  array('field' => 'lastname',
    'label' => 'lastname',
    'rules' => 'required'
  ),
);

$middle_name = array(
  array('field' => 'middlename',
    'label' => 'middlename',
    'rules' => 'required'
  )
);

$config = array(
  'fullname' => array_merge($first_last, $middle_name), //first, middle and last name fields
  'shortname' => $first_last, //only first and last name fields
);
```

This provides two different sets of fields for use with `form_validation->run()`.

For example: On a form using first, middle and last name fields

```
if($this->form_validation->run('fullname'))
{   
   ...
```

Or, when the form contains only the first and last name fields

```
if($this->form_validation->run('shortname'))
{   
   ...
```

Comment: actually, I have dynamic form, It will return 2 fields or three fields or one field not sure. It totally depends on the customer. that's why I used only one set of rules

Comment: The idea is adaptable and the rule-set used can be selected dynamically too.

Comment: $first_last=array(// rules) I have to make like this and pass to $config = array(// rules) ?

Comment: And I have more than 30 fields in the form. It totally depends on the user. How many fields he can use it.

Comment: With that many fields you probably don't want to use `form_validation.php` to define sets of rules. You will need to use `set_rules()` as fields are dynamically added to the form.

Comment: I thought there are more than 30 fields and it will be easy to use the form_validaiton.php. More then 30 fields then it will display lots of  set_rules() code in the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156367/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-dfriend).

Comment: can you share the example?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you are requiring a field that does not exist. You either need to:

- Add a field in your view with the name `middlename`
- Remove the validation rule that requires a field `middlename` to exist

Not contributing to your issue, but in a usability aspect, you likely want to change the label in your `lastname` and `middlename` rules to make them more user friendly.

```
$config = array('test'=>array(

 array('field' =>'firstname', 
       'label' => 'First Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
),
    array('field' => 'lastname',
          'label' => 'lastname',
          'rules' => 'required'
          ),

 array('field' => 'middlename',
       'label' => 'middlename',
       'rules' => 'required'
     )
 ),
);
```

Also, the documentation has other helpful tips for different custom rules if you're not trying to require the `middlename` but want to sanitize or validate its format prior to insertion into a database.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Comment: Actually the issue is I have more than 30 fields and it totally depends on the user how mya field he requires with validation.

Comment: So the fields shouldn't be required then, because they'd be required every time. Without knowing more about the different views, the logic of which fields are required when, etc, it might be easier to have different methods in your save controller and set the appropriate save URL based on the form.

Comment: The idea of this form of validation is you're telling it the rules for which fields have to be in which format. If it's a single form that has different rules based on the value in a different field, then you'd likely want to look at the custom rules in the documentation I attached in my answer.